# Bitblt operation shows no result in Delphi

Tags: delphi, bitmap

I have an Image1 (TImage) and a Mask and Sprite (TImage) with B/W pictures assigned to them at designtime. Now I want to BitBlt Mask and Sprite onto Image1 to get a transparent image:

```
BMPmask := TBitmap.Create;
BMPsprite := TBitmap.Create;
try
  BMPmask.Assign(Mask.Picture.Bitmap);
  BMPsprite.Assign(Sprite.Picture.Bitmap);
  BitBlt(Image1.Canvas.Handle, 50, 50, 96, 96, BMPmask.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SrcAnd);
  BitBlt(Image1.Canvas.Handle, 50, 50, 96, 96, BMPsprite.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SrcInvert);
finally
  BMPmask.Free;
  BMPsprite.Free;
end;
```

but when I run my program nothing shows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TImage is for showing images. It isn't a general drawing surface. Create a bitmap. Blit to that. Then assign that bitmap to the images picture. And don't ignore return values when calling API functions. The two bitmaps you create in this code seem pointless. Why make copies of bitmaps that you already have.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what you describe is exactly what this code is doing. The `TImage` is creating a `TBitmap` that the code is then blitting to. The image is likely not displaying because the `TImage` doesn't know the bitmap has been drawn onto. Try calling `Image1.Invalidate;` after drawing. I agree that copying the original bitmaps is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: @Remy Is that right. The Canvas property is always valid and always backed by a bitmap? I thought that the image control was backed by a TPicture which can hold an arbitrary graphic.

Comment: @DavidHefferman - I'm using the intermediate bitmaps to avoid getting the runtime error "Can only modify an image if it contains a bitmap". A problem I posted about before, and to which you answered to do exactly this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - See my comment to David above. The `invalidate` doesn't help. Thanks for your time, though.

Comment: That doesn't ring true. I can't imagine I would have suggested copying the bitmap rather than using `Mask.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle`. And I wonder if you really should be using `TImage` at all for the mask and sprite. Shouldn't they live in a `TBitmap`. Do you need to show them to the user?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, `TImage` is backed by a `TPicture`, but `TImage.Canvas` is backed by `TImage.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas`, so using `Canvas` requires `TPicture` to hold a valid `TBitmap`.

Comment: @JorisGroosman the "Can only modify an image if it contains a bitmap" error means the `TImage` is not holding a `TBitmap` when you access its `Canvas`. That has nothing to do with your mask/sprite images. If they are already bitmaps to begin with, you do not need to make copies of them, just use them as-is. On the other hand, if they are not bitmaps, you do need to copy them to bitmaps first, but copying them using `Picture.Bitmap` will *wipe them out* (as explained in the `TPicture` documentation), and that could explain why you don't see anything. Use `Picture.Graphic` instead when copying.

Comment: I don't know if this is what is going on here, but a remarkably common Delphi anti-pattern is the use of `TImage` for image processing. It looks very much like you are falling for that anti-pattern. My instincts tell me that this code should not involve any `TImage` instances at all. You should be working with bitmaps. If, down the line, when you have merged the two images, you want to display to the user, then assign the merged bitmap to your `TImage` control. But stop using `TImage` when you should be using `TBitmap`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how do you initialize Image (there is no point in the question - maybe it is not initialized?). Simple example works as expected:

```
unit Unit60;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm60 = class(TForm)
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    ImageDst: TImage;
    ImageMask: TImage;
    ImageSprite: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
  end;

var
  Form60: TForm60;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm60.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImageDst := TImage.Create(Form60);
  ImageMask := TImage.Create(Form60);
  ImageSprite := TImage.Create(Form60);
  Button1 := TButton.Create(Form60);

  ImageDst.Name := 'ImageDst';
  ImageDst.Parent := Self;
  ImageDst.Left := 24;
  ImageDst.Top := 24;
  ImageDst.Width := 249;
  ImageDst.Height := 281;

  ImageMask.Name := 'ImageMask';
  ImageMask.Parent := Self;
  ImageMask.Left := 279;
  ImageMask.Top := 24;
  ImageMask.Width := 128;
  ImageMask.Height := 128;

  ImageSprite.Name := 'ImageSprite';
  ImageSprite.Parent := Self;
  ImageSprite.Left := 279;
  ImageSprite.Top := 158;
  ImageSprite.Width := 128;
  ImageSprite.Height := 128;

  Button1.Name := 'Button1';
  Button1.Parent := Self;
  Button1.Left := 288;
  Button1.Top := 303;
  Button1.Width := 75;
  Button1.Height := 25;
  Button1.Caption := 'Button1';
  Button1.OnClick := Button1Click;
end;

procedure TForm60.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Mask,Sprite,Dst: TBitmap;
begin

  { create bitmap within TImage }
  Dst := ImageDst.Picture.Bitmap;
  Dst.SetSize(ImageDst.Width, ImageDst.Height);

  { prepare some mask & show it at bottom }
  Mask := ImageMask.Picture.Bitmap;
  Mask.SetSize(128, 128);
  Mask.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  Mask.Canvas.FillRect(TRect.Create(32, 32, 96, 96));

  { prepare some sprite & show it at bottom  }
  Sprite := ImageSprite.Picture.Bitmap;
  Sprite.SetSize(128, 128);
  Sprite.Canvas.Ellipse(TRect.Create(16,16,112,112));

  { draw to image }
  BitBlt(Dst.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Mask.Width, Mask.Height, Mask.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SrcAnd);
  BitBlt(Dst.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Sprite.Width, Sprite.Height, Sprite.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SrcInvert);
end;

end.
```